# detecting when new files are added

Tags: php

Will be starting a new project soon and not sure what the best option to do this is. I need to be able to detect when a new file has been added to a web server (Apache). I expect the file structure will grow quite large so I don't think php will be suitable. Has anyone any suggestions on best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at inotify extension.

If you don't want to use php, you can use directly [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=common&page=home&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I am looking for. Was thinking of using perl and a cron job but this looks perfect thanks